# Clickable semi circle chart configuration issue

Tags: angular, highcharts

Currently i am working on a requirement, which user can click on the plotted area of a semi circle chart and route to a new page inside the application.I also need to give a different out puts according to clicks on different portions of piloted areas...I have gone through the Highchart API and come up with an solution, but my code snitpet is not working..can any one help me with this please.

```
this.chart = new Highcharts.Chart('container', 
    {
      chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: 0,
        height: 400,        
        plotShadow: false
      },
      title: {
        text: '98',
        style: {
          "fontSize": "48px"
        },
        align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        y: 50
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
     },
      tooltip: {
        pointFormat: 'Test: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>',
        enabled:false
      },
      colors: ['#FF0000', '#FFA500', '#FFFF00'],
      plotOptions: {
        pie: {
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            distance: -100,
            style: {
              fontWeight: 'bold',
              color: 'white'
            }
          },
          point: {
              events: {
                click: function (e) {
                  alert("Clicked");
                }
              }
            },
          startAngle: -90,
          endAngle: 90,
          center: ['50%', '75%'],
          size: '110%'
        }
      },
      series:[
        {
           data: [
            {y: 1, name:"", id:"0"}, 
            { y: 7, name:"",  id:"1"},
            { y: 2, name:"", id:"2"}
           ],
           innerSize: '65%',
            type: 'pie',

        }
     ]
    }

  );
```

Comment: Which statement is exactly not working?

Comment: click event is not working....No alert is fired after click on plotted area...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missing binding to the context change your click event as below:

```
events:{
    click: (function(e) {
      console.log(e.point);
      if(e.point.name == "1"){
        alert('Clicked 1');
      }
      else if(e.point.name == "2"){
        alert('Clicked 2');
      }

    }).bind(this)
}
```

Comment: Thanks User3250, But I need to give a different out puts according to clicks on different portions of piloted areas...

Comment: You can `e.point.name` to run conditional statements. See my edit.